# Filling the field of the datum form automatically with the date of today

Tags: php

I am building a web page for an admin dashboard using PHP and I have the following code, for the input date form and what I want is that if the "startdatum" is empty it must fill today's date in automatically.

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="startdatum" id="startdatum" name="startdatum">
```

Comment: How are you checking if the form input is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:
Btw, the `<input type="date">` isn't supported on safari.

This example assumes that the input tag will always be empty when showing up, the user can later change the values.

```
<?php

$a = date("Y-m-d");

?>

<input type="date" id="startdatum" name="startdatum" value="<?php echo $a ?>">
```